# gradle shell script dockerfile

Tags: bash, shell, gradle, dockerfile

Having issue getting the exit code in dockerfile

```
RUN bash -c " \

if [ $FLAVOR = E2ETEST ] ; then \
  
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests abcTest;\
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests cdeTest -PtestType=\"e2e\" executeE2ETests; \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests defTest ; \
```

the flavor comes from yaml file
how could i get the exit code for the 3 gradle command

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example that will allow us to reproduce your results. There's not enough detail here to help you. Try adding more info about the issue you want help with

Comment: in bash you can get an exit code of the previous command by `$?`. e.g: `bash -c "exit 12"; echo $?` will print 12

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you can get an exit code of the previous command by `$?`. e.g:

```
bash -c "exit 12"; echo $?
```

will print 12.

In your case, you can save exit codes to variables, however, it can be some problems in getting them because of Dockerfile specialties (you can't export them to environment variables to use in next `RUN`). Depending on how do you want to use it, you can, for example, write it into a text file, or do something in that script:

```
RUN bash -c " \

if [ \"$FLAVOR\" = E2ETEST ] ; then \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests abcTest; EX1=\"\$?\"; \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests cdeTest -PtestType=\"e2e\" executeE2ETests; EX2=\"\$?\"; \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests defTest; EX3=\"\$?\"; \
  echo \$EX1 \$EX2 \$EX3" > /tmp/exit_codes; \
fi"
```

also, it's better to take $FLAVOR in parentheses, because it will produce error if $FLAVOR is empty.
`$` are escaped because docker expands the expression during parsing.

And if you just need to check if commands succeeded, just replace `;` with `&&` (the following `RUN` will fails if any command exits with non-zero exit code):

```
RUN bash -c " \

if [ \"$FLAVOR\" = E2ETEST ] ; then \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests abcTest && \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests cdeTest -PtestType=\"e2e\" executeE2ETests && \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests defTest; \
fi"
```

To run all commands and get exit code 1 if any of them fails do

```
RUN bash -c " \

if [ \"$FLAVOR\" = E2ETEST ] ; then \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests abcTest; EX1=\"\$?\"; \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests cdeTest -PtestType=\"e2e\" executeE2ETests; EX2=\"\$?\"; \
  ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests defTest; EX3=\"\$?\"; \
  if [ $EX1 == 0 ] && [ $EX2 == 0 ] && [ $EX3 == 0 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi; \
fi"
```

Comment: Thanks taras for the explanation. I want to execute the all 3 gradle commands and should exit 1 at the end if any of command fails. What can i do for that?

Comment: Added the solution you asked for

Comment: From where variable EX1,EX2,EX3 coming??

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to add them. Fixed

Comment: bash: line 0: [: ==: unary operator expected. getting this issue now so even if the gradle build is successful it's doing exit 1

Comment: sorry, there was a typo (EX2 after 3rd command), fixed

Comment: that i got but i'm getting this error in docker . line 0: [: ==: unary operator expected

Comment: ./gradlew clean :app:testDevDebugUnitTest --tests cdeTest; EX2=\"\$?\";\
      if [ $EX2 == 0 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi; \

if i do this only still its failing giving me [: ==: unary operator expected error